# What is the proper way to upgrade ExtJS Libraries specifically from 5.0 to 5.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, upgrade, sencha-architect, extjs5

I ONLY use Sencha Architect to develop my applications **without using CMD or any of the cmdline features** and dont intent to use them as well.

Recently (after the release of Extjs 5.0) I downloaded Architect 3.1 that comes with 5.0 as the base library. Everything was straight forward and worked fine and easy **until 5.1.0 was released**.

How do I upgrade my existing applications (that use 5.0), to 5.1.0. There are a few important bugs fixed in this release that I want to implement.

I have no knowledge or experience using CMD and hence I have never taken that approach in the past. I always followed the Right Click Library -> Select Upgrade to  and Done.

But on the Architect 3.1 I dont get that option to Upgrade using UI.

***What I have tried so far:***

1) Downloaded the 5.1 library from my support page.

2) Dropped the new 5.1.0 folder in my application's ext/gpl folder..

3) By default the **Library base path** was `ext/gpl/5.0.1/build`, I have changed it to `ext/gpl/5.1.0/build`

4) Publish the application, publishes to the new directory

But when I run the application using `http://localhost/MyApp/index.html`, I get an error and the page does not load

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                       ext-all.js:19
```

5) As soon as I change the library base path to 5.0.1, everything works fine.

I am not sure what I am missing and what is the proper way to do this. I really need to upgrade the library to 5.1

Contents of my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <script>
        var Ext = Ext || {};
        Ext.theme = {
            name: ""
        };
    </script>
    <script src="ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-gray/build/ext-theme-gray.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-gray/build/resources/ext-theme-gray-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customGrid.css" id="CustomGridCSS">
    <script src="config.js" id="arConfigSettings"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a support contract with ExtJS?

Comment: Yes. I do. @RobertHarvey If you mean with Sencha

Comment: Then I suggest you get them on board.  That's what they're there for.

Comment: You must have already got it working!!

Comment: https://www.enovision.net/upgrade-sencha-ext-js-application-workspace/